# Magento2 : Order Success Observer For Admin Order

Tags: magento2, admin

Does anyone know how to call observer for admin order success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `events.xml` file here and you can use `checkout_submit_all_after` event there.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="admin_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AdminOrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one Observer file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AdminOrderPlaceAfter.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class AdminOrderPlaceAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/observer.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Backend order placed.');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks @Kishan Working Great !!!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_order_place_after">
      <observer name="vendor_module_sales_order_place_after"
           instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderPlaceafterSaveData"/>
   </event>
</config>`
Put this code in `events.xml` then create **Observer** directory and in there
`use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;`
`class OrderPlaceafterSaveData implements ObserverInterface`

and make your magic happen